# How do I use inline styling with WordPress?

Tags: css

I would like to be able to add a background image to the header area on each inside page of [this site](http://anchor.opteradev.com/the-firm/). On a static page I would do something like this:

```
<header class="entry-header" style="background: url('/images/bg_the-firm.jpg')no-repeat left top;">
```

However, any attempts at inline styling are stripped out by WordPress. I can add a background image using the theme's style.css, but I need to be able to add a unique image for each page: hence the inline styling necessity.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to specify template directory in your inline background style too.
Use it like this.

```
<header class="entry-header" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/bg_the-firm.jpg')no-repeat left top;">
```

If WordPress strip your inline styles, you can use body classes to add specific styles to each page.

Each page have some body classes, you can find those in page source in any browser. And define your header background like this in your `style.css`.

```
body.page-id-6 header.entry-header{background: url('images/bg_the-firm.jpg') no-repeat left top;}
```

Make sure you define page specific styles at the end of `style.css` to avoid overwriting it's effect.

Comment: Hi Robert, this is what I added to the page: `<header class="entry-header" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('anchor-engineering'); ?>/images/slider.jpg')no-repeat left top;">`, but if you check the page, there is no indication that it is there.

Comment: actually you don't have body classes in your `header.php`. make sure you have `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`.

Comment: Your page id is 6 for `THE FIRM` page so use `body.page-id-6`. I made changes in code. Add it to at the bottom of your `style.css`